# How is reference box being calculated here?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the code below, it looks like the `%` value for `transform: translate()` refers to the `width|height` dimension of `shiftingDiv`.

This [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate) says `%` refers to the reference box as defined by `transform-box`. Here, `transform-box: view` is being applied which means the reference box is the nearest SVG viewport. What does this mean in the example below?

```js
button.addEventListener('click', handler);

function handler() {
  shiftingDiv.classList.add("move");
}
```

```css
.move {
  transform: translate(100%, 100%);
}

div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Click to shift div</button>
<div style="position: relative; left: 200px">I am 200px out</div>
<hr>
<div id="shiftingDiv">I am shifting</div>
<div>I am 200px below</div>
```

Comment: The size of the element, the `div` in this case. You move the element 100% of it's own size down and right.

Comment: @RickardElimää I've edited the question to show I want to know how the 'reference box' is being calculated here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transform-box):

> For elements **with associated CSS layout box**, the used value for `fill-box` is `content-box` and for `stroke-box` and `view-box` is `border-box`.

The default value (`view-box`) will simply fall to `border-box` in case of non-SVG elements:

> border-box
>
> Uses the border box as reference box. The reference box of a table is the border box of its table wrapper box, not its table box.

I think it's trivial that your reference is the dimension of the element itself including its border

Answer (score -1):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate)

> This value describes two  or  values representing both the abscissa (x-coordinate) and the ordinate (y-coordinate) of the translating vector. A percentage as first value refers to the width, as second part to the height of the reference box defined by the transform-box property.

In short, this means it's the percentage of the element that the `transform` property is on.